# How to create multiple null matrices in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, null

I would like to create `18` null matrices of the same dimension named as `mat10ci`, `mat15ci`,...., `mat95ci`. I have tried the following code

```
for( s in seq(10,95,by=5)){
  paste0("mat",s,"ci")=array(NA, dim = c(10, 20))
}
```

I am having this error

```
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to deal with multiple matrices in the same way, I strongly suggest you put them in a `list`, very similar to the [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272) discussion. For instance, `lst_of_mtx <- lapply(seq(10,95,by=5), function(ign) array(dim = c(10, 20)))`.

Comment: Or frankly, you could deal with it as a single 3d array, as in `array(dim=c(10, 20, 18))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm inferring that you're going to be doing the same (or very similar) things to each matrix, in which case the R-idiomatic way to deal with this is to keep them together in a list of matrices. This is the same approach as a "list of frames", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272.

For a list of matrices, try:

```r
lst_of_mtx <- replicate(18, array(dim = c(10, 20)), simplify = FALSE)
```

As an alternative, depending on your processing, you could do a single 3d array

```r
ary <- array(dim=2:4, dimnames=list(NULL,NULL,paste0("mat", c(10, 15, 20, 25), "ci")))
ary
# , , mat10ci
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# , , mat15ci
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# , , mat20ci
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# , , mat25ci
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

where you can deal with just one "slice" of the array as

```r
ary[,,"mat25ci"]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `list2env` + `replicate`

```
list2env(
  setNames(
    replicate(18, array(NA, dim = c(10, 20)), simplify = FALSE),
    paste0("mat", seq(10, 95, by = 5), "ci")
  ),
  envir = .GlobalEnv
)
```

When you type `ls()`, you will see

```
> ls()
 [1] "mat10ci" "mat15ci" "mat20ci" "mat25ci" "mat30ci" "mat35ci" "mat40ci"
 [8] "mat45ci" "mat50ci" "mat55ci" "mat60ci" "mat65ci" "mat70ci" "mat75ci"
[15] "mat80ci" "mat85ci" "mat90ci" "mat95ci"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `assign` :

```
for( s in seq(10,95,by=5)){
  assign (paste0("mat",s,"ci"), array(NA, dim = c(10, 20)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
lst1 <- vector('list', 18)
names(lst1) <- paste0("mat", seq(10, 95, by = 5), "ci")
for(nm in names(lst1)) {
       lst1[[nm]] <- array(dim  c(10, 20))
 }
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or an option with `tidyverse` using `rerun`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
18 %>%
    rerun(array(dim = c(10, 20))) %>% 
    set_names(str_c("mat", seq(10, 95, by = 5), "ci")) %>% 
    list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```